# addclass removeclass on pagination

Tags: jquery, html

I've some problems with this piece of code I've been asked to work on.

```
function rebuildPager( to_show ){

var item_per_page = 10;
var items = $('#video-container .span3.'+to_show);
var pager = $('#navigation-container .nav-video');

pager.html('');

if(items.length > item_per_page){

    var total_page = Math.ceil( items.length / item_per_page );
    var el_page = 1;
    //console.log(total_page);
    items.each(function(index, element) {

        if( index!=0 && ( (index) % (item_per_page) == 0 ) ) { el_page++; }
        $(element).attr('data-item_page' , el_page );

    }).promise().done(function() {

        //add prev link
        pager.append('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showThisPage(\'prev_page\')" class="prev_page" data-show_page="prev_page"><</a></li>');

        //add pages links
        for( i=1; i<=total_page; i++) {
            pager.append('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showThisPage(\''+i+'\')" class="numerate_page" data-show_page="'+i+'">'+i+'</a></li>');
        }

        //add next link
        pager.append('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showThisPage(\'next_page\')" class="next_page" data-show_page="next_page">></a></li>');

        $('#video-container').attr('data-current_page' , 1);
        $('#video-container').attr('data-total_pages' , total_page);
        $('#video-container').attr('data-current_showing' , to_show);
        $('#video-container .span3.'+to_show+'[data-item_page="1"]').fadeIn(400);
    });


} else {
    items.fadeIn(700);
}
}
```

then the function for changing page state

```
function showThisPage(show_page) {

var current_page = $('#video-container').attr('data-current_page');
var to_show = $('#video-container').attr('data-current_showing');
var total_pages = $('#video-container').attr('data-total_pages');
var page_to_show = "";

if( show_page == current_page) { return; }

if( show_page == 'next_page' ){ page_to_show = parseInt(current_page)+1 ; }
else if( show_page == 'prev_page'){ page_to_show = parseInt(current_page)-1 ; }
else { page_to_show = show_page; }

if( page_to_show < 1 || page_to_show > total_pages ) {
    return;
} else {

    $('#video-container .span3').fadeOut( 700 ).promise().done(function() {

        $('#video-container .span3.'+to_show+'[data-item_page="'+page_to_show+'"]').fadeIn( 700 ).promise().done(function() {

            $('#video-container').attr('data-current_page' , page_to_show);

        });

    });

}

$.scrollTo( $('#select-content'), 800 , {
    axis: 'y',
});

}
```

I'd like to add a class of "current-page" to the first page on load and change it when another page link is clicked.
I've tried to add the following piece of javascript but it doesn't remove the class. All clicked pages keep the class "current-page".

```
$(".nav-video li a").click(function(event) {
    $(this).addClass("current-page").siblings().removeClass("current-page");
});
```

Help will be sincerely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nav-video li a").click(function(event) {
    $(this).addClass("current-page").siblings().removeClass("current-page");
});
```

In that code, $(this) refers to the A tag that the user clicked on. Try using $(this).closest('.page')...

Answer (score 0):

With this code, when a link is clicked it gets the "current-page" class (great), but this element has no siblings (it is alone in its "li" tag). I assume you have a pager like

```
<ul>
    <li><a ...>...</a></li>
    <li><a ...>...</a></li>
    <li><a class="current-class" ...>...</a></li>
    <li><a ...>...</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

...and you want to keep track of the clicked "a" tag with a "current-page" class on it. So what you need to do is more like

```
$(".nav-video li a").click(function(event) {
    // remove the current class on the previously clicked <a> tag
    $(".nav-video li a.current-class").removeClass("current-class");
    // add the current-class to the clicked <a> tag
    $(this).addClass("current-page");
});
```

It should do the trick.